# Updating the kABPersonPhoneProperty using an NSString to add a phone number

Tags: ios, addressbook, core-foundation

I have a Contact object (a class that I wrote) that I want to use to create a new AddressBook person. Here is my code:

```
+ (ABRecordRef)createABPersonFromContact:(Contact*)contact
{
    ABRecordRef person = ABPersonCreate();

    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, contact.firstName, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty, contact.lastName, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonOrganizationProperty, contact.company, NULL);

    CFStringRef phoneNumberValue = (CFStringRef)contact.phoneNumber.value;
    CFStringRef phoneNumberLabel = (CFStringRef)contact.phoneNumber.label;

    ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumber = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumber, value, label, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumber, NULL);
    CFRelease(phoneNumber);

    return person;
}
```

contact.phoneNumber.value is an NSString in the format "555-555-5555". When I run the code and display an ABPersonViewController with the ABRecordRef returned by this method, every thing displays properly, but if I try to edit the phone number, the program crashes. I tried reformatting the NSString contact.phoneNumber.value to "(555) 555-5555" to match the style that the phone number is displayed in the ABPersonViewController, but it gave me the same result.

Any suggestions as to why it is crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I should have been using kABMultiStringPropertyType instead of kABPersonPhoneProperty for phoneNumber.

Comment: To clarify, `ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty)` is the bit that's wrong. It should be `ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType)`. Unfortunately the incorrect example seems widespread online. In certain cases it even appears to work without crashing, which made it hard for me to figure out where the problem was!